# Clojure - close over a function in another namespace

Tags: clojure, closures, clojurescript

Let's say that I have the following :

```
(defn my-fn [params]
  (make-things (a-fn [ctx]
                 (do-this params)))
```

Now I wish to split this into different files, such that a-fn is in another namespace :

```
(defn my-fn [params]
  (make-things my.ns/a-fn))
```

But the problem now is that the `params` doesn't close over my function anymore. How should do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite:

```
(defn my-fn [params]
  (make-things (fn a-fn [ctx]
                 (do-this params)))
```

into

```
(defn my-fn [params]
  (make-things ((fn a-fn-o [p]
                 (fn a-fn [ctx]
                   (do-this p)))
                params)))
```

This is what the compiler does for you when you close over variables.

Then it should be clear what to do in your other file. The function returns a function and you pass in `params`:

```
(defn my-fn [params]
  (make-things (my.ns/a-fn params)))

;; my.ns
(defn a-fn [params]
  (fn [ctx] (do-this params)))
```

Btw, your `ctx` parameter is unused.

Answer (score 1):

Just so that's mentioned too, you might instead of closures also want to consider [using a Var to  scope the params dynamically rather than lexically](http://clojure.org/vars). This is especially useful if they're "implicit arguments" to several related functions in `my.ns`.

```
(ns my.ns)

(def ^:dynamic *params* ...) ;;Optional default value here

(defn a-fn [...]
   (do-this *params* ...))
```

and then in the calling ns

```
(defn my-fn [params]
  (binding [my.ns/*params* params]
    (my.ns/a-fn ...)))
```

This is how for instance `with-out-str` alters the behaviour of any `print` variant both in its body and in subcomputations - by rebinding `*out*` to an empty string writer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use partial:

```
(ns my.ns)

(defn a-fn [params ctx]
  (do-this params))
```

Then in the calling context:

```
(defn my-fn [params]
   (make-things (partial my.ns/a-fn params)))
```